# Polygon function under lines

Tags: r, plot, line, polygon

I have a plot and i added a line with the line function and I would like to fill the area below the new line with the polygon function. But I find it hard since I don't know what to put in polygon.
Can someone help ?

```
rmelange <- function(n, alpha, l0, l1, p0, p1) {
  z <- rbinom(n, 1, alpha)
  f1 <- eval(parse(text = paste("r", l1, "(", paste(c(n, p1), collapse = ","), ")", sep = "")))
  f0 <- eval(parse(text = paste("r", l0, "(", paste(c(n, p0), collapse = ","), ")", sep = "")))
  x <- z * f1 + (1 - z) * f0
  return(x = x)
}
dmelange <- function(t, alpha, l0, l1, p0, p1) {
  res <- alpha * eval(parse(text = paste("d", l1, "(t,", paste(p1, collapse = ","), ")", sep = ""))) + (1 - alpha) * eval(parse(text = paste("d", l0, "(t,", paste(p0, collapse = ","), ")", sep = "")))
}

x <- rmelange(100, 0.2, "norm", "norm", c(5,5), c(5,5))



uii <- dmelange(seq(-35, 35, length.out = 100), 0.2, "norm", "norm", c(5, 5), c(5, 5))



plot(density(x, bw = "nrd0", kernel = "e"), ylim = c(0, 0.7), main = "Densité donnée par notre estimateur contre la véritable densité", cex.main = 0.99)

lines(seq(-35, 35, 0.001), dmelange( seq(-35, 35, 0.001), 0.4, "norm", "norm", c(1, 2), c(5, 9)), col = "red", lwd=2.5)

polygon(seq(-35, 35, 0.001), dmelange( seq(-35, 35, 0.001), 0.2, ,lwd=5, col = rgb(1, 0, 0,alpha = 0.5))
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of issues with your functions.

Firstly, `demelange` doesn't actually return anything (you haven't returned `res` at the end).

Secondly, your method of pasting together function calls as text, parsing them, then evaluating them is inefficient, complicated and unnecessary. You can instead build your arguments as lists and use `do.call`.

Thirdly, your code lines are very long, which makes it difficult to debug. It's OK to use line breaks in the middle of function calls. This isn't just a minor style point - it really does make it harder to find problems when you have to scroll backwards and forwards through a long and complicated line of code.

Outside the function calls, you could probably re-use your variables more. When you use `seq` for example, store the result instead of recalculating the same sequence several times.

All these things aside, you were very close to getting `polygon` to work. You just hadn't closed your own function call. I suspect that has to do with the long code lines and lack of re-using variables.

Anyway, putting all this together, we get:

```r
rmelange <- function(n, alpha, l0, l1, p0, p1) {
  
  z  <- rbinom(n, 1, alpha)
  f1 <- do.call(paste0("r", l1), list(n = n, mean = p1[1], sd = p1[2]))
  f0 <- do.call(paste0("r", l0), list(n = n, mean = p0[1], sd = p0[2]))
  z * f1 + (1 - z) * f0
}

dmelange <- function(t, alpha, l0, l1, p0, p1) {
  
  l1 <- do.call(paste0("d", l1), list(x = t, mean = p1[1], sd = p1[2]))
  l0 <- do.call(paste0("d", l0), list(x = t, mean = p0[1], sd = p0[2]))
  alpha * l1 + (1 - alpha) * l0
}
```

And

```r
xvals <- seq(-35, 35, length.out = 100)
x     <- rmelange(100, 0.2, "norm", "norm", c(5,5), c(5,5))
uii   <- dmelange(xvals, 0.2, "norm", "norm", c(5, 5), c(5, 5))

plot(density(x, bw = "nrd0", kernel = "e"), 
     ylim = c(0, 0.1),
     main = "Densité donnée par notre estimateur contre la véritable densité", 
     cex.main = 0.99)

lines(xvals, uii, col = "red", lwd = 2.5)

polygon(xvals, uii, lwd = 5, col = rgb(1, 0, 0, alpha = 0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks !  But one thing I don't get is why when I paste your code I still get nothing but when i put col="red" it works. Do you have an idea ?

Comment: The above example works as a full reprex, so my guess is that your device doesn't handle alpha transparency? Are you using an up to date version of R and Rstudio?

Comment: Yes, I've used alpha before so I don't get the error.

Comment: Can you perhaps try restarting RStudio, with a clean workspace, then copy and pasting my exact script?

Comment: Thanks it finnaly worked i had to update also R, I thought by updating rstudio it will do both.